# NSUInteger string encoding 32 and 64 bit

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, 64-bit

I am trying to figure out the best way to convert an NSUInteger into a string that works for both 32- and 64-bit systems. I see that NSUInteger is defined differently for both platforms and I want to make sure what I am doing is correct.

All solutions I have seen required some casting, or seem incorrect. I get a warning with the code below asking me to add an explicit cast.

```
NSUInteger unsignedInteger = PostStatusFailed; // This is an enum
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"postStatus == %lu", unsignedInteger];
```

I have also tried `%d` (signed ints, which doesn't seem correct), and `%lx`, but none seem correct. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried %u as format specification?

Comment: That seemed to work without warning. That should work for 64-bit as well?

Comment: I think it should, but I have no Mac at hands now to try out.

Comment: It won't. For 64-bit, NSUInteger is `unsigned long` whereas for 32-bit, it's `unsigned int`. You'll get a warning if you use `%u` for NSUInteger and are compiling a 64-bit binary.

Comment: @neilco Yeah, you're right.

Answer (score 6):

From the [String Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html):

> OS X uses several data types—`NSInteger`, `NSUInteger`,`CGFloat`, and
>   `CFIndex`—to provide a consistent means of representing values in 32-
>   and 64-bit environments. In a 32-bit environment, `NSInteger` and
>   `NSUInteger` are defined as `int` and `unsigned int`, respectively. In
>   64-bit environments, `NSInteger` and `NSUInteger` are defined as `long` and
>   `unsigned long`, respectively. To avoid the need to use different
>   printf-style type specifiers depending on the platform, you can use
>   the specifiers shown in Table 3. Note that in some cases you may have
>   to cast the value.

See the link for all of the types.  For `NSUInteger`, the correct approach is:

```
NSUInteger i = 42;
NSString *numberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu is the answer to life, the universe, and everything.", (unsigned long)i];
```

Comment: @Bilko, you are correct.  I was obviously confused when I tried it out.  Thanks.  I deleted my original comment saying that it caused a warning as I've tried it again and it doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [**64-bit Transition Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/Major64-BitChanges/Major64-BitChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013501-CH2-SW8):

> The compiler defines the **LP64** macro when compiling for the 64-bit runtime.

So you can do something like this:

```
#if __LP64__
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"postStatus == %lu", unsignedInteger];
#else
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"postStatus == %u", unsignedInteger];
#endif
```

Comment: Is there any nice way to do this with the if-else?

Comment: @JamesPaolantonio You could do a check on the size of `unsigned long`, i.e. `if (sizeof(unsigned long) == 4) { /* 32-bit */ } else { /* 64-bit */ }`

Comment: Sorry, I meant without the if-else.

Comment: No, there is not. There's no universal format string for NSUInteger.

Comment: This is not a great way of doing this. See Aaron Berger's answer below, which conforms to Apple's recommendations: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW5

Answer (score -1):

In a 32-bit environment, NSInteger and  NSUInteger are defined as int and unsigned int, respectively. In 64-bit environments, NSInteger and NSUInteger are defined as long and  unsigned long, respectively.

so have a NSNumber for best way.

when you want get a NSString, like this formate to NSNumber then.

```
NSUInteger unsignedInteger = PostStatusFailed; // This is an enum
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"postStatus == %@", @(unsignedInteger)];
```

%@ ---> @(NSUInteger),  you see @(), it's a NSNumber.